# How can I write conditionals in a PromQL regex?

Tags: regex, prometheus, grafana, promql, re2

I have a custom Grafana variable `$var`, which I use in my Prometheus queries to retrieve some data. Based on the value of this variable, the label value of the metric I'm using should be changed accordingly. In other words, I would like to use a conditional on this variable within regex. See example below:

```
some_metric{my_label=~"(?($var=val1)label_val1|label_val2)"}
```

The above query would result in `my_label` being equal to `label_val1` if `$var` equals to `val1`, and `label_val2` in all other cases. However, this doesn't seem to be supported by the *RE2* syntax, which Prometheus uses for regular expressions. Is there any other way to achieve this behavior?

**Note:** the `$var` variable controls most of the other variables in my dashboard, and it already has a [key/value mapping](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/27829) in place, so I cannot go for this workaround. I was thinking about creating an additional custom variable, which would also depend on `$var`, however it seems that Grafana does not support this either.

Comment: RE2 does not support any lookarounds, conditionals, etc. You cannot use a plain regex approach like that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there any workaround for that in Prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround could be the [key/value custom variable](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/27829) available since **Grafana Version 7.3**.

You would create a variable and have key value pairs:

```
val1 : label_val1, val2 : label_val2
```

[image]

---

Then in your PromQL, you would reference the variable as normal:

```
some_metric{my_label=~"$var"}
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot use this workaround, since the variable `$var` already has another mapping in place, which I can't get rid of. This variable controls most of the other variables in my dashboard. I was even thinking about creating an additional custom variable, which would also depend on `$var`, but it seems like Grafana does not support chaining of two custom variables either...